# How to show alert in extjs?

Tags: extjs

While executing the following code in browser it will not shown an alert, its just shown empty page. anything wrong in the following code please help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text.html; charset=utf-8">

<title> First Program </title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href ="http://localhost:8080/ext/ext-4.2.1.883/resources/css/ext-all.css"/>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://localhost:8080/ext/ext-4.2.1.883/ext-all-dev.js"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Ext.onReady(function(){
        //  alert("We are ready to go!");
        Ext.Msg.alert("Hello World");
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since ExtJS 4, the preferred way to launch your application is using `Ext.application({launch: function(){}})` instead of `Ext.onReady(function(){})`.

Answer (score 11):

You are not calling the method properly. `Ext.Msg.alert` takes two parameters, `title` and `message`, as you can see in the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.window.MessageBox).